# Is there a term for politicians enacting a policy where the negative consequences will be far after their political career is over?

Tags: political-theory, terminology

For example, Governor Newsom has [recently committed to banning internal combustion engine cars](https://www.wsj.com/articles/california-to-ban-sales-of-new-gas-powered-cars-starting-in-2035-11600882738) starting from the year 2035 or **15** years from now. Given that this will be long after he's out of office, it wouldn't harm his career in the slightest if the proposed ban ends up as a failure.

As another example, politicians used to set up generous pension funds for government employees. These pension funds ended up to be a complete disaster for local budgets several decades later, but by that time the politicians who enacted the laws have long retired so they couldn't have possibly suffered any adverse consequences.

Is there a proper term for such political maneuvers?

NB: let's avoid discussing Governor Newsom, the effectiveness of combustion engine bans or public pension plans. This question is purely about terminology.

Comment: Negative consequences for the politician? Or negative consequences for the electorate?

Comment: I don't imagine there is a technical term, as it's a really broad category of things. Short term thinking is how I would phrase it, but election cycles are too short for anything else to actually be of interest to your average politician.

Comment: This might do better over on English Language & Usage. They field questions like this all the time. My own suggestions would be along the lines of "performative", "posturing" and "kicking the can down the road".

Comment: Many decisions require long-term planning; longer than the typical term of an elected official.  Most political decisions require trade-offs; if there are no negatives either way, there's no difficult decision.  Hence, future negative consequences of planning which extends beyond a politician's term is just called _politics_.

Comment: Yes, there is: Democracy.

Comment: Negative consequences of the policy?

Comment: kicking the can down the road?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim lets say California's ban ends up a complete failure and politicians have to promptly backtrack it in 2036. Newsom wouldn't risk his re-election odds if that is the case.

Comment: @JonathanReez What is a "failure"? Is it a failure because it was ineffective (everyone just buys cars in NV instead), or because it failed to appreciably do anything about carbon emissions? Your last comment suggests it was so *unpopular* it was retracted, making the attempt a failure, regardless of how it worked?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim yes, failure in the opinion of the voting public, regardless of objective metrics

Comment: So political negative consequences?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim correct

Comment: Gotcha, well then, I like the answer that's given

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [Kicking the can down the road](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Kicking%20the%20can%20down%20the%20road)

Examples:

- https://www.abc.net.au/news/2020-05-19/coronavirus-rental-hardship-pushed-down-the-line/12259322
- https://abcnews.go.com/blogs/politics/2012/04/senate-budget-chair-defends-kicking-the-can-down-the-road/
- https://tasmps.greens.org.au/media-release/gutwein-must-commit-donations-reform

This is the action of delaying a problem till much later - as often done by politicians with tricky problems, but unfortunately this is not unique to political manoeuvring.

Eg here is it used with reference to Australian banks : https://smallcaps.com.au/banks-keep-kicking-266-billion-can-down-the-road/

---

Aside
With your specific example; The transition to electric vehicles is going to take a long time as you have old vechiles being resold and used for 20+ years - I'm driving a 17 year old car currently. I want to save the environment but can't afford a new car. 15 years is actually pretty fast for this transition, too fast to work perhaps.

Comment: Also, on the electric car thing, a governor or legislature  in say 2030 could either extend the deadline by many years- to 2040 or 2050 say- or scrap the whole thing.

Comment: The electric car thing is more setting a target than imposing a restriction on the future. Something involving large-scale pollution, mass deforestation/environmental destruction, or risking future pandemics (e.g. loosening restrictions on antibiotic use in agriculture) might be more relevant.

Comment: This expression is in the Cambridge dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kick-the-can-down-the-road in case you want a more reliable source than urban dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Another, less common but more dramatic term is [**"Stealing from our Children's Future"**](https://www.agriland.ie/farming-news/everyday-our-emissions-go-up-we-are-stealing-from-our-childrens-future/)

It's often used in the context of [national debt](https://www.heritage.org/debt/commentary/addressing-the-biggest-threat-our-childrens-future-unsustainable-national-debt), which will have to be repaid by our descendants and of [global warming](https://www.transportxtra.com/publications/evolution/news/60665/climate-change-poses-moral-questions-for-the-work-of-transport-professionals/) which may cause them massive environmental problems.